# Root mean square current

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-current, short-circuits

An electric bulb is designed to operate at 12 volts DC. If this bulb is connected to an AC source and gives same brightness , what would be the peak voltage of the source?

To this question answer is 12√2V
My doubt is that since this bulb can only operate upto 12V when maximum value of AC voltage will be 12√2 (peak value) the bulb will fuse.
Am I right? Pls verify

Answer (score 3):

If the bulb was connected to a $12 \sqrt 2 V$ DC source then it would run too bright and probably blow.

However, if connected to a (sinusoidal) AC source with a peak of $12 \sqrt 2 V$ then it will only experience the excess power for a fraction of a cycle.  For much of the cycle, it will be receiving less power than from a a $12V$ DC source.  The $\sqrt 2$ comes from a bit of mathematics which shows that the energy received in one cycle will be the same as a $12V$ DC source in the same period.

If the frequency of the source was extremely low e.g. a cycle per hour then it may overheat in the portion of a cycle when the voltage was above $12V$.  In a typical AC source with a frequency of $50Hz$ or $60Hz$, this period is too short to overheat it.

Fill your kettle with cold water and turn it on.  It will eventually get to $100C$ but not instantly.  The filament of the bulb is much smaller and will heat up more quickly than the kettle of water but not so quickly that it will overheat in the fraction of a second that the voltage is over $12V$.

Buy two kettles, one with a rating of $1000W$ and one with $2000W$ but otherwise similar.  Add the same amount of water to each.  Turn on the $1000W$ kettle and leave it on.  Turn the $2000W$ one on for a second, off for a second, and repeat.  The total energy going into each will the same and they will reach $100C$ at a similar time.

Note that I am assuming a simple, old style filament bulb which works just by getting hot.  Other technologies e.g. fluorescent tubes, and LEDs will behave quite differently.  For a filament bulb, 12V RMS AC will have a similar affect to 12V DC but maybe not for other types.

Comment: I added a clarification that I was assuming filament bulbs.  Thanks to Bob D for mentioning that.

Answer (score 0):

> To this question answer is 12√2V My doubt is that since this bulb can
> only operate upto 12V when maximum value of AC voltage will be 12√2
> (peak value) the bulb will fuse. Am I right? Pls verify

You didn't say what kind of bulb it is, but let's assume its a tungsten filament bulb.

Normally when one speaks of "fusing", it means opening due to overheating. In that case, a 12 volt ac rms source (12$\sqrt 2$ peak voltage) has the same heating effect on the bulb as a 12 vdc source. So the 12 ac source would not cause the bulb to fail due to overheating.

However, a bulb also has a voltage rating. Whether or not it would fail due to the peak voltage exceeding 12 volts would depend on the bulb technology.

Hope this helps.